# Getting the date from Javascript comes up with bizarre values

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I want to get the date and time in the following format:

`yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss` | `2014.11.6.20.31.24`

However, my code (based on [Get Current Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456712/how-to-get-current-time-with-jquery)) is instead providing these values:

`y??.m?.d?.hh.mm.ss` | `114.10.4.20.31.24`

Here is my code:

```js
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + "." + dt.getMinutes() + "." + dt.getSeconds();
var date = dt.getYear() + "." + dt.getMonth() + "." + dt.getDay();
alert(date + "." + time);
```

Can someone please let me know why these odd values are in there `114.10.4` and how to change them to be what I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you need to use

- [`.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) for the full year
- the [`.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is 0-based so you need to add 1
- the function to get the day of month is [`.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate). The [`.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) is for the day of the week.

```js
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + "." + dt.getMinutes() + "." + dt.getSeconds();
var date = dt.getFullYear() + "." + (dt.getMonth()+1) + "." + dt.getDate();
alert(date + "." + time);
```

---

If, for some weird reason, you are going only for firefox, you can use

```
var d = new Date(),
    formatted = d.toLocaleFormat('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S');

alert(formatted);
```

---

Finally, you can use the great [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library and do

```
var formatted = moment().format('YYYY.MM.DD.HH.mm.ss');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong getters. Use `getFullYear()` instead of `getYear()`, and `getDate()` instead of `getDay()`. And add 1 to the month, because it starts at 0.

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + "." + dt.getMinutes() + "." + dt.getSeconds();
var date = dt.getFullYear() + "." + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "." + dt.getDate();
alert(date + "." + time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you are using methods what you want to use e.g:

`dt.getYear()` => `dt.getFullYear()`

For further reference see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Answer (score 0):

should use `getFullYear()` instead of `getYear()` and `getMonth() + 1` instead of `getMonth()` because it calculate form 0..11 and info about [getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + "." + dt.getMinutes() + "." + dt.getSeconds();
var date = dt.getFullYear() + "." + dt.getMonth() + 1 + "." + dt.getDate();
alert(date + "." + time);
```

`dt.getDay()` this day of the week

Answer (score 0):

The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6)

You need to use `getDate()` to know the number of the day (from 1 to 31)

Also, you need to add 1 to `getMonth()` because months in JavaScript starts on 0