# How to start timer from current machine time using query?

Tags: jquery

I am getting current time when page loads and I want to start timer from current time. How can I do this?

Here is my current script:

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
$("#timer").text(time);
```

Comment: first time i get time by this method then i want to start timer automatically to show time as machine's clock displays

Comment: So basically you are looking for a clock?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456712/how-to-get-current-time-with-jquery)

Comment: wrap it in `setTimeout(function(){ //code here }, 1000);`......XD

Comment: basically time will be sent from server then timer will start time from that given time and loops on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```js
var dt = new Date();
setInterval(function() {
  dt.setSeconds(dt.getSeconds() + 1);
  var time = pad(dt.getHours(), 2) + ":" + pad(dt.getMinutes(), 2) + ":" + pad(dt.getSeconds(), 2);
  $("#timer").text(time);
}, 1000)

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num + "";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: no this code is getting current machine time. i will be given with server sent time. i will loop on it and display time just like the clock

Comment: I added this code but this only works when page is active i mean for the duration until page is focused but when i navigate to other tag time stops and when i navigate back to this tab instead of 1 minute it only passed 10 or 12 seconds. Kindly help me with this. I think browser lows it down in priority

Comment: @SaadAhmed when you go to some page and come back, then you need to get the time from server again.

Comment: ok i got it but isn't there any other solution without taking input again from server?

Comment: @SaadAhmed I don't believe so. I am not able to think of any fail safe techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these 3 lines in a fuction and use `setInterval()`

```
function showTime(){
    //var dt = new Date();
    //var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

    //var time = [add a ajax call to your server and get the time in string format.]
    $("#timer").text(time);
}
setInterval(showTime,1000);
```

So the fuction is called each second and the div is updated with current time.

Comment: I don't want to get it from current machine.Time will be sent from server in php